# How did the rise in fees for UK universities change the way things function?

Tags: university, united-kingdom, fees, governance

Tuition fees for UK universities rose to £9,000 a year for the 2012–13 academic year (not in Scotland for Scottish or EU students).

Other than meaning students had a larger debt to pay back to the government, what else changed? Did this mean the services got better, or staff were paid more?

I don't really want to debate about whether or not this was a good thing, just interested on the effect the an increased flow of money from the government to university.

Comment: Do you mean 2022-23?

Comment: Wasn't it just to compensate for less government (tax supported) funding?

Comment: There was no increased flow. All that happened was the money, rather than being paid by the government as a grant, was paid by the government and charged to the student.

Comment: So pre  2012–13 academic year, the government were paying the difference of approximately £6000 (funded by taxes)?

Comment: I have no data to back this up, but I was at uni around this time and it certainly felt like less people were interested in attending after the fee cap increased. So it may also be worth looking into wether the available student "market" shrunk as a result of the change.

Comment: Opinion rather than fact, so I will make this a comment rather than an answer: there has been a shift from universities being places of _learning_ to universities being places of _teaching_. Perhaps not unreasonably, students object to paying £9k and then being expected to go to the library and work things out for themselves.

Comment: @DanielAdams Sort of. Prior to 2012-2013 universities recieved a "teaching grant" from the government. This wasn't explicitly on a per student basis. Instead the government determined an amount, and then universities decided how many students they could afford to recruit based on that. The amount of money was the same irrespective of how many students they recruited (in the short term, in the long term if they recruited too few the grant might be reduced).

Comment: The level of the fee was set such that the total amount of money in the system would be more or less the same after the reforms as before. But that doesn't mean that each faculty/university got the same per student.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a couple of commenters said, there was not really a net increase in funding to universities. The decision was made to put more of the financial burden of education onto the student rather than the state. See this [UK government briefing paper](https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/sn06206/). So no salary increases, etc. This was in the context of the UK recovering from the 2008 financial crisis.

In addition to reducing government spending on higher education, this also had the (intentional) effect of driving the marketization of higher education by turning students into consumers. This has led to universities competing with each other for students (ie. fees). Universities have therefore invested more time and money in the student experience in order to attract more students. For more discussion about this competition for students and it's effects on UK universities, see [this article](https://www.economist.com/britain/2017/02/23/growing-competition-between-universities-is-changing-student-life).

So I suppose in an indirect way it may have led to some improvements in the student experience, although I would argue that the marketization of higher education has far more negatives than positives...

A clarification about the fees: The current *cap* on university fees is £9250 per year for UK home undergraduate students. Universities can, and a few do, charge less than this (all of the top universities charge the maximum). International student (including EU) and postgraduate tuition fees are uncapped.

Comment: I am specifically interested in the marketization of higher education, and whether the competition for students (as consumers) is having bad consequences.

Comment: @DanielAdams Probably should be a separate question. But an interesting question! However, probably wouldn't get a very balanced opinion from academics who are pretty universally against the marketization of higher education.

Comment: @DanielAdams, For what it's worth, I would say that the consequences are bad for students, staff, and academia in general.

Comment: Hi Atom, could you clarify the sentence comment "competing with each other for students (ie. fees)", surely they were already competing for student 'fees' (they were just paid for by the government).  Is it more they need to compete to 'please students', who are now more selective in their university choice because they are effectively paying for it themselves?

Comment: @DanielAdams. Unfortunately it's complicated and also tied up with other changes which happened at the same time/since (eg changes to caps on student numbers, student loans, etc). I don't really want to digress too far into this topic in this answer, but I have added a link to an article which discusses it. Your last sentence is a significant part of it, I believe, but not the entire story.

Comment: Thanks will give it a read

Comment: @DanielAdams See my comments on the question. But no, Universities were not competing for student fees (paid by the government) as it wasn't a case of recruiting as many students as they could that the government then paid a fixed amount per student for.