How did the 2012 rise in university fees in the UK affect university enrollment?
Did the number of domestic students decrease ?
Did international students start to make up a larger % of UK university enrollment?

I don't have data so not an answer. But two points to be aware of: 1. The 2012 changes were not just an increase in fees but also a change in how fees were paid (from up-front to 'graduate tax'). 2. International enrolments have certainly grown - but the driver here is that the fees+government support for domestic students have not changed since 2012 and so have been devalued by inflation.

related (don't think duplicate?): https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/186925/how-did-the-rise-in-fees-for-uk-universities-change-the-way-things-function

I don't see how this is off topic, it's about university enrolment and thus clearly about academia. Voting to reopen.

The data you are looking for can be found at:
https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/cbp-7857/
and is summarised in the following figure from that link:

Breilfy, there was a drop in applications in the 2012-2013 year, but numbers quickly recovered. Overseas numbers have increased over the period, the fraction of undergraduates from overseas does not look like it has increased to me.
